# Программа должна вычислять непрерывно до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет слово

Tags: c++

Программа должна вычислять непрерывно до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет слово. То, что у меня получилось:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
#define G 9.8;

int main()
{

        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
        double v;
        double a;
        double dist;
        std::cout << "Введите значение скорости (для выхода введите 'exit'):\t";
        std::cin >> v;
        std::cout << "Введите значение угла (для выхода введите 'exit'):\t";
        std::cin >> a;
        std::cout << "Дальность:\t\t\t\t\t\t" << (v*pow(sin((PI * 2 * a) / 180), 2)) / G;



        _getch();
        return 0;       
}
```

Comment: Ок. А в чем вопрос-то?

Comment: Программа должна вычислять расстояние , непрерывно спрашивая
величину угла и начальную скорость до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет слово exit

Comment: Это вы своё домашнее задание опубликовали. А вопрос-то какой? Вы хотите, чтобы за вас код написали? Нет, этого не будет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не публикуйте код в комментариях. Добавьте его в вопрос с помощью кнопки [edit]. А ещё, пожалуйста, **сформулируйте вопрос**.

Comment: PI == `M_PI` из `cmath`; `while(std::cin >> cmd) { if(cmd == 'exit') exit(0); double angle = std::stod(cmd.c_str()); ... }`

Answer (score 3):

```
while(true) { 
   ...; 
   break; 
}
```

как-то так наверное

Comment: Да, теперь понятно. Но решение слишком общее и в нем нет ничего про ввод слова.

Answer (score 2):

В качестве шаблона для вашей собственной программы вы можете использовать следующую программу

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    while ( true )
    {
        const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
        const double G = 9.8;

        std::string input;

        std::cout << "Введите значение скорости (для выхода введите 'exit'): ";
        std::getline( std::cin, input );

        if ( input == "exit" ) break;

        double v = std::stod( input );

        std::cout << "Введите значение угла (для выхода введите 'exit'): "; 
        std::getline( std::cin, input );

        if ( input == "exit" ) break;

        double a = std::stod( input );

        std::cout << "Дальность:\t\t\t\t\t\t" << ( v * std::pow( std::sin((PI * 2 * a) / 180), 2)) / G;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }    
}
```

Конечно вы можете ее усовершенствовать, например, переводя введенные данные в строку `input` в нижний регистр, чтобы пользователь мог вводить слово `exit`, в любом регистре и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вроде этого

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char toEnter[4];
    do
    {
        // твои операторы
        cin.getline(toEnter, 4, '\n');
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        toEnter[0] = toupper(toEnter[0]);
    } while (strcmp(toEnter, "C++"));
}
```

Comment: Ага, вот так хорошо.